# Craft asset urls not working

Tags: assets, error-message, siteurl

I have checked all other questions on stack exchange with similar titles and they don't seem to help my situation. 
I have added assets sources to craft CMS. but when uploading I get the following error:

> The error message was: "Error uploading the file:  The file system path "{siteUrl}assets/images/hero-images/" set for this source does not exist."

I am working locally using MAMP. I do not have multiple environments. only local.

the *siteUrl* variable seems to work fine when used directly in templates. just doesn't work for assets.

File system path is

```
assets/images/hero-images/
```

URL is

```
{siteUrl}assets/images/hero-images/
```

General config is set to

```
return array(

    // Base site URL
    'siteUrl' => "//projectname:8888/html/",

    // Environment-specific variables (see https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-environment-configs#environment-specific-variables)
    'environmentVariables' => array(),

    // Default Week Start Day (0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday...)
    'defaultWeekStartDay' => 0,

    // Enable CSRF Protection (recommended, will be enabled by default in Craft 3)
    'enableCsrfProtection' => true,

    // Whether "index.php" should be visible in URLs (true, false, "auto")
    'omitScriptNameInUrls' => 'auto',

    // Control Panel trigger word
    'cpTrigger' => 'admin',

    // Dev Mode (see https://craftcms.com/support/dev-mode)
    'devMode' => false,

);
```

If I open the assets in chrome, this is their file path.

```
http://projectname:8888/html/assets/images/hero-images/be-inspired-mobile.jpg
```

This is driving me mad and have checked everything.

I am using exactly the same config settings as all my other sites which work absolutely fine.
Any help will be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

As per the Craft Docs at https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-environment-configs#environment-specific-variables, add a `basePath` (or other name) variable to you config. For MAMP, it should look something like:

`'basePath' => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/example.dev/public/'`

Then in your asset source settings, change File System Path to:

`{basePath}assets/images/hero-images/`

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to work. 
Also using MAMPs given url (//projectname:8888/html/) as {siteUrl} seems to work fine in all my other projects. 
I also do not keep my sites in MAMPS htdocs folder, i keep them in a separate 'sites' folder so that I can work on more than one at once.

Comment: Andrea's answer is definitely correct. Any time you have `{tag}`s within your asset sources' File System Path or URL settings, their values will be swapped out with the environment-specific variables, which are defined by the `environmentVariables` array  in general.php. Your array is empty, so it's expected that it wouldn't work for you.